# vector::clear :Memory Issue

Tags: c++, stl, mfc, vector

Vector::Clear() will erase the elements in the vector array.

The issue is that if we pass objects in vector list then Clear() will delete the memory of objects or not.

I post my sample:

```
     CData *m_data = new CData();
     vector<CData*> m_logdata;
     m_logdata.push_back(m_data);
     m_logdata.clear();
```

will this code delete the memory allocated by m_data or simply remove the element in the vector list?

Regards,
karthik

Comment: Store a smart pointer in the vector and you don't have to worry...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no Vector, there is a vector though.

vector.clear() will destruct the objects in the vector. If these objects are pointers, it will not delete the pointed to objects.

```
struct Foo {
};

vector<Foo> vec1;
vector<Foo *> vec2;

vec1.push_back(Foo());
vec2.push_back(new Foo());

vec1.clear(); // Will destruct the Foo instances
vec2.clear(); // Will not delete the pointed to Foo instances
```

On your edited post:

```
m_logdata.clear();
```

This will *not* delete your `CData` instance. It'll simply destruct the *pointer* which is a no-op.

EDIT: In response to comment.

```
for (size_t p = 0; p < m_logdata.size(); ++p)
  delete m_logdata[p];
m_logdata.clear();
```

Comment: @Erik:How to delete CData Instance?Please provide solution for this.

Comment: If you want to store pointers and these should be deleted when the container is clear'd, you should use some kind of smart pointer instead, e.g. boost::shared_ptr. These will automatically free their object if they are destructed.

Comment: @karthik: Loop over the elements and do `delete`

Comment: @Erik:Thank you for providing valuable feedback

Comment: @Erik: Hi Erik ,When i Tried in my application ,it throws runtime exception ...i will show the error  HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED:the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.How to overcome this Erik.

Comment: @karthik: Post a new question including enough code to reproduce the problem - likely your CData class is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite vague... but either way, I guess that you are wondering if pointers stored in a `vector` would automatically be deleted when `clear()` is called.

This is not the case. Whatever you store in a `vector` will have its destructor called when `clear()` occurs. And the destructor of a primitive type (such as a pointer) does.. nothing.

From my SGI implementation:

```
/**
 *  Erases all the elements.  Note that this function only erases the
 *  elements, and that if the elements themselves are pointers, the
 *  pointed-to memory is not touched in any way.  Managing the pointer is
 *  the user's responsibilty.
 */
void
clear() { erase(begin(), end()); }
```

To properly delete items pointers in any STL container, the easiest way is to create a functor and apply it on every item:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename ValueT>
struct func_delete : public std::unary_function<ValueT,void>
{
  void operator()( ValueT& item ) { delete item; }
};

struct Foo
{
  ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo()" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename ContainerT>
void delete_container( ContainerT& container )
{
  std::for_each( container.begin(), container.end(), func_delete<typename ContainerT::value_type>() );
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::vector<Foo*> foos;

    foos.push_back( new Foo );
    foos.push_back( new Foo );
    foos.push_back( new Foo );

    // Either of these two lines will work
    //std::for_each( foos.begin(), foos.end(), func_delete<Foo*>() );
    //delete_container( foos );

    foos.clear();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```